# Pine Script v5 - Identifying the Candles AFTER not before

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5, candlestick-chart

how can I address the candles AFTER the candle I have found a condition in.
for example i have identified a doji candle as
dojicandle =math.abs( (open-low) ) >= math.abs(dojimultiplier*(close - open))

for previous candles we have open[1] but for afterward candles I couldn't find anything.
I wanna find out whether the next candle is a bullish one or not

Answer (score 0):

for me (i am not an expert of pine-script) the current candle is the "0" one. The one before is the "1". You should retreive the number corresponding to the candle you search for (which is not the "0" one

Answer (score 0):

Predicting the future isn't possible
We can only access the current and past candles.

Or, did you mean you're trying to detect a bullish candle happening right after a DOJI candle?

If that's the case, I'd do it like this

```
bullishCandle = close > open
if dojicandle[2] and bullishCandle[1]
     ...
```